# Free software for recording Skype session on Linux

Tags: linux, screen-recording, skype

Can anyone recommend a free software for recording Skype sessions on Linux? I specifically need it for Ubuntu and CentOS. I need the software to be capable of recording

1. Audio only
2. Video only
3. Both audio and video
4. Ability to record the remote video and the video from the camera on my localhost.

This would be really useful for keeping track of things people speak at conferences and stuff.

It must keep recording the Skype video even if other windows cover it (I am doing other things when recording, and want to watch the video later).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) (free and open source):

https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11702/16704 :

> This command will capture your full desktop: So use this command,
>   whenever you want to record skype-conversation ( or anything else ):
>
> `ffmpeg -f x11grab -s wxga -r 25 -i :0.0 -sameq /tmp/out.mpg`

If you prefer using a GUI you can use [recordMyDesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) (free and open source):

[image]

Comment: The things that you suggested are just screen recorders. This means I have to keep the skype screen on top of others for the entire session. The main reason I need this is to record skype sessions when I am busy doing other things on my computer so that I can view it later. I guess this will not work for my requirement because I cannot switch screens during recording. But pretty good softwares so +1 for that.

Comment: @VivekVK Try "select window" and then pick your skype session. Dunno if that will work or not.

Comment: @Seth yeah I am able to do it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

[OBS](https://obsproject.com/) should do exactly what you need. It's designed for streaming but it also works for screen-recording and can be set to record a specific window which, if i recall correctly, will mean that it can record a window even if it is being covered by/is behind other windows or applications.

Also for anyone else who is interested, OBS also has a "replay recording" feature where, instead of recording a full gameplay session (or whatever) and editing it down to "the good parts" after, you can set it up such that OBS will just be recording to memory in the background and whevever you click the "save replay" button, OBS will save the last 20-seconds or so (duration depends on how much memory you allow OBS to use for this) as a video clip in a configured location. This often used by streamers to save particularly awesome moments of gameplay moments after they happen, but it will also work for anything you plan to record using OBS.

Oh and it's open source and allows you to specify varying combinations of inputs and outputs like you specify in your question, as this overlaying and combining different inputs is something streamers do quite often (like putting their webcam feed in the corner, picture in picture style, so viewers can see them and the gameplay)